# How to stop huge consumption of internet data by Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: internet, 20.04, network-monitoring

For the past 5 years, I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. During that time, I didn’t face any unwanted internet data consumption issues. Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I haven't installed any other software yet. I configured auto update settings as below. [Ubuntu 20.04 software & update settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP1vG.png)

Even after the above settings, Ubuntu 20.04 consumes around 1 GB of internet data within a few minutes in idle state (not browsing anything). I am using Wi-Fi hotspots internet data from mobile. Please help guide me to stop this huge unintended consumption of internet data by Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: What traffic occurs? or how are you measuring it?  I find it hard to believe, as I've not noticed any differences in traffic  to prior releases (and I've used 20.04 for ~six months during the development cycle). Are you talking desktop? server? did you clean install? or how did you switch?  I suspect it's a setup issue (when you moved from 14.04 to 20.04 where you provided no details, and that is an unsupported jump so it matters)

Comment: Does it consume data continuously, or was it just during the update period?

Comment: Would change update settings to daily or weekly,  instead of never(my opinion).  Use nethogs from the answer to see what is using it.

Comment: @guiverc: Thank for your response. I installed desktop version alongside dual boot windows 7. I measured data lose through my mobile data.

Comment: @ Soren A: While installing time it took ~300 MB of data. Immediately I checked in my mobile. After few minutes I found 1.3 GB of completed in my mobile through Tethering & portable hotspot data usage. In this way I measured. That time laptop only was tethered.

Comment: @ Soren A: In my other laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS also I face these kind of issues last 2 years. One particular time it consumes like this. That time I stopped my tethering connection. After few hours I reuse the net connection in my laptop. That time it works smoothly. I couldn't find where the problem is. Any guidelines?

Comment: Is it only during install and soon after, or is it continuing?  Depending on type and timing of install, some do download updates at install so you have have a fully updated system at reboot.  This is an option you choose.  If it continues after reboot that is a problem.  It does seem to be a lot though.

Comment: @ crip659: Thank for your response. After reboot and after sometime while I open my laptop also I faced this problem. I restrict my mobile data 30 MB to 50 MB from my current data level. When I face this problem I disconnect the tethering connection to avoid the data lose. This problem I faced in one laptop last 2 years with Ubuntu 18.04. So I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in another laptop. There also same problem.

Answer (score 12):

You have to find out which process use your bandwidth, you should install and use nethogs to check how much which process use:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/nethogs.8.html

Comment: I will check nethogs command when I face this problem and let you know. Not this problem all times. Some times I face this problem and lost huge data. Is the browser may be the reason? I used Google chrome. Which browser is recommendable in Ubuntu?

Comment: Your browser may be an issue but not to the limit of > 1GB still you could avoid a lot of bandwidth by using an ad blocker like "ublock origin" or directly opt for a built in anti ad browser like "Brave"

Comment: But I lost > 1GB just after installing Ubuntu 20.04 in one laptop. That time period nothing I did. The frequent data loss in another laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 mostly in morning when I first open my laptop and connect to internet. Some other random times also I faced this  problem often.

Comment: I am finding that firefox if left open for a few days will tend to use bandwidth at a constant 300 or 400kib/s.

Comment: But this problem I didn't face in Ubuntu 14.04 for the last 5 years where I installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: I faced this problem in Ubuntu 18.04 and above only.

Comment: 300 or 400kb for firefox is huge it should be almost 0 most of the time, you clearly have something running behind

Comment: @Saxtheowl  I know, most of the time it stays near zero except for blips.  Think one of the extensions get wonky after a few days, maybe weather or VPN(good paid)

Comment: Maybe its because of auto download updates. please check your updater settings once

Answer (score 3):

Adjust automatic update settings in [Software & Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates).

To hold updating snaps when on a metered connection.

```
sudo snap set system refresh.metered=hold
```

Snaps update automatically, and by default, the snapd daemon checks for updates 4 times a day. To only refresh snaps on the last Friday of the month:

```
sudo snap set system refresh.timer=fri5
```

More information about the date-time formats that the snap CLI supports can be found [here](https://snapcraft.io/blog/how-to-manage-snap-updates).